# Inyección de dependencias con listas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, patrones-de-diseño, inyeccion-de-dependencias

¿Si tengo dentro una clase tengo una lista `List<ILibro> Libros` debería inyectar esas dependencia?

```
public class Persona 
{
  public List<ILibro> Libros {get; set;}
  public ITelefono Telefono {get; set; }
  
  public Persona(List<ILibro> libros, ITelefono telefono)
  {
    Libros = libros; 
    Telefono = telefono; 
  }

}
```

Comment: que dependencia queres inyectar? y como?

Comment: la lista de ILibro

Comment: creo que no entiendo tu termino.. a que te refieres con inyectar? quien quieres que la inyecte?